# Hadoop S3 Configurations cannot be set on the Spark Session Running in a Cloudera Environment (CDH 6.3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

We can set the following configs on the HDFS service (core-site.xml) using Cloudera Manager UI:

```
fs.s3a.access.key
fs.s3a.secret.key
```

However, this will affect the whole cluster. All Spark jobs running within the cluster will use these same configs to access S3.

We'd like to be able to configure the S3 bucket & access on each spark job independently.

Using spark-shell, we can use the following commands to successfully query a Hive table stored in S3:

```
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
scala> spark.sql("select count(1) from <database>.<table>").show()
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
| 100|
+--------+
```

However, setting the same configurations programmatically in our Java code won't work for the same query to the Hive table.

Approach 1 (Using spark.hadoop.* configs):

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
```

Approach 2 (Using 'hadoopConfiguration' and no 'spark.hadoop' prefix):

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

Both approaches won't work. When the Java-based Spark job runs, it gives error:

```
The directory s3a://<bucket>/path/to/database/table/<table>/file_name=file_23300820194892734.parquet was not found. Was it deleted very recently?
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|0 |
+--------+
```

Is this a known issue? Any workaround for it?

Comment: I think approach 2 doesn't take as it may be too late to set the options. Check with someone else there. For approach 1: it should. Try setting it in the spark-default file to see if it is picked up in that

Comment: Thanks stevel. For approach 2, that's what I thought too, but using the spark-shell, it worked even after the session was created. Approach 1 doesn't work either for me. Also, I don't want to set it in spark-default.file because I want the keys to be different for each spark job.